# Cannot watch Youtube videos on any app

Tags: windows-10-mobile, apps, microsoft-edge

I use PerfectTube and Tubecast for watching youtube videos. Everything was working fine until yesterday. Now I can barely watch any of the videos, especially the songs. For example: I listen to [this song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RoDPPgWbfXY) each and everyday. Now I cannot watch it on any youtube client app and even on mobile version on Edge, it says, "The video is not available." It works on desktop version of Edge. the case is not specific with a particular one, but infact it is same with  almost every song. I tried so many videos and none of them work. Other non-song videos are working fine. This is really strange. There's no audio and video playback.

It's same on another windows device. I tried it on android, and everything seems to be working there. Maybe google is blocking video playback on windows device? If not, what's the case? My device is fine. My internet is fine too.

Comment: Actually that's video is not available in my android too. So that's a YouTube problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see videos not playing in Microsoft Edge, or any client that shows videos, its a **storage space** issue. Apparently the operating system storage space, specifically the phone's memory in order to playback videos. I suspect you have little space in your phone memory (<100mb) Whenever my on-board storage goes below 80 megabytes, the same issues you mentioned start occurring.

Open your phone's file manager, and try moving some files from the phone's storage into your Micro SD card if you have one in the phone. You can also delete unwanted files, move them to your computer. Also, open storage sense, and check what applications have "overgrown". There are some applications, like WhatsApp, that accumulate size when they have been installed for a while. You might uninstall, then reinstall those apps as an alternative way of retaining gobbled up storage space.

*Try it out and comment the result.*

Comment: The issue is with the app itself. I have around 2GB of free storage on both SD card and phone. Tubecast updated their app with new algorithm and now I can play the videos. However, PerfectTube still hasn't updated their app. I installed one more youtube app(tubetube) but I hate having three apps for same purpose. PerfectTube is my primary youtube client. It has more control. Anyway, thanks for trying :)

Answer (score 1):

In edge it says, "The video is not available, but in tubecast it is playing without any issues, If you are an insider(fast ring) previous build has some issues with 3rd party youtube apps. build 15025 solves the issues for me, if still has a problem try to soft reset

Comment: yes, it is now playing in tubecast now :) Thanks!